# Convert decimal to string without commas or dots

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET, I need to convert a decimal amount (money) to a numbers-only string, i.e:
123,456.78 -> 12345678

I thought

```
var dotPos = amount.ToString().LastIndexOf('.');
var amountString = amount.ToString().Remove(dotPos);
```

would solve my problem, or at least part of it, but it didn't work as I expected.
I'm trying to do this possibly without writing a lot of code and using something already designed for a similar purpose.

Comment: yourNumber.ToString().Replace(',','').Replace('.', '')

Comment: _"but it didn't work as I expected"_ - then you didn't read the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx): _"Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position, have been deleted."_. So `"123,456.78".Remove(7)` will yield `123,456`.

Comment: That's what I found out as well. The hard way :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var amountString = string.Join("", amount.Where(char.IsDigit));
```

Using the `char.IsDigit` method will protect you from other unknown symbols like `$` and will also work with other currency formats. The bottom line, you don't know **exactly** what that string will always look like so it's safer this way.

Comment: Whitespaces too (depending on the localization)

Comment: Cheers, it worked. Though Resharper suggested it writen like this:
    var amountString = string.Join("", amount.Where(char.IsDigit));

Comment: +1 You could make it shorter `...amount.ToString().Where(Char.IsDigit)` which is also more efficient.

Comment: You could also do `var amountString = string.Concat(amount.ToString().Where(char.IsDigit));`

Answer (score 10):

You say it's an amount, so I expect 2 digits after the decimal. What about:

```
 var amountstring = (amount * 100).ToString();
```

to get the cents-value without delimiters?

Or maybe even

```
var amountString = ((int)(amount * 100)).ToString();
```

to make sure no decimals remain.

**EDIT**
If a cast to `int` isn't quite what you want (It would just ignore any extra decimals, like [Math.Floor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.floor)), you can also use one of the [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round) overloads, for instance:

```
var amountString = Math.Round(amount * 100, MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString();
```

The [MidpointRounding.ToEven](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding) (also known as ["Banker's Rounding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)) will round a .5 value to the nearest *even* value, instead of always to the next *higher* value.

Comment: Valid for ***Money*** and ***Double*** types, not ***Decimal*** type

Comment: It could works with decimal if you use Math.Round(value, 2). Example: long valueInCents = ((long)(Math.Round(value, 2) * 100));

Answer (score 2):

You don't need casts, you don't need to know where the decimal is, and you *certainly* don't need Linq. This is literally a textbook-case of Regular Expressions:

```
Regex regx = new Regex("[^0-9]");
var amountString = regx.Replace(amount, "");
```

Couldn't be simpler. And you can pass it strings with other odd monetary characters, or *any character at all*, and **all** you will get out is the decimal string.

Comment: I don't think there's an overload of Regex.Replace that takes a decimal as input argument. So, you'll be casting amount to a string before running the regex on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var amountString = amount.ToString().Replace(".","").Replace(",","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var amount = 123456.78;
var amountString = amount.ToString().Replace(",", "").Replace(".","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say this may help you: `var res = amount.ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "");` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var amountString = amount.ToString().Replace(",",string.Empty).Replace(".",string.Empty);
```

**This will replace all the "," commas and "." decimal from the amount.**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
value.ToString("D")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: This throws `FormatException` seems Invalid for floating point types