# C# String format: escape a dot

Tags: c#, .net, string, string.format

I have a line of code, something like:

```
mbar.HealthLabel.text = String.Format("{0:0.0}", _hp);
```

Output is: 2.25 for example. Is it possible to escape a dot from the output string view with String.Format function ?

For. ex. 225,

To make my question more clear, I need the same effect like:

```
Math.Floor(_hp * 100).ToString();
```

But need to do it by `String.Format` template.. Thanks.

Comment: what is the original string in `_hp`?

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to use String.Format?

Comment: Try doing _hp.Replace(".", "") which replaces dot with empty string

Comment: right, just use the Math.Floor alternative you proposed yourself :)

Comment: If the underlying problem is that you've only got access to modify the string format, rather than the code itself, you should probably mention that.

Comment: Like this: `mbar.HealthLabel.text = String.Format("{0:0.0}", _hp * 100);` ?
Note, that string format for numeric values depends on regional settings!

Comment: Is your number always 2 decimal places - like converting dollars to cents? Or could it be `1.2345` and you want that to be `12345`

Comment: Possibly of interesting is the % custom format specifier which will multiply a number by 100 and add a percentage sign. You may not want this but on the off chance this is being formatted as a percentage it may be useful. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you can do it this way

```
double value = 1.25;

var stringValue = string.Format("{0:0}", value * 100, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //125
```

**EDIT:**
More general solution would be to `Replace` the dot with empty string as stated in the comments.

```
double value = 1.25;

var stringValue = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(".",string.Empty);
```

**EDIT2:** Also there is [another general idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810211/convert-decimal-to-string-without-commas-or-dots) that do not use `Replace` function (but also it does not use the `String.Format`)

```
var stringValue = string.Join("", value.ToString().Where(char.IsDigit));
```

Also another similar idea:

```
var stringValue = new string(value.ToString().Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: This is what i exactly suggest in the comment to the question.

Comment: Yes, and the sent time shows both of us were thinking at the same solution at the same time.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: I'm assuming (hoping?) that was just an endorsement of your answer rather than any kind of accusation of copying.

Comment: @MaciejLos if you had an answer you should have posted one. Answers in comments are unhelpful

Comment: The way I read the question was that the OP is just requiring the output string to have no dot in it - and that 2.25 was just an example. You solution would only work for values with 2dp.

Comment: @PaulF: The OP explicitly says that they want the equivalent of `*100`.

Comment: @Chris: I took it that that was the effect he wanted for that particular example - the question asks about "escaping a dot". It may be that the OP does want the value to 2dp with no dot in - in which case the answer is valid.

Comment: Your edit probably needs localization consideration - what if the decimal separator is not a "."? May not be relevant for the OP but you should always bear in mind that decimal and thousand separators (and maybe other elements) may not be consistent.

Comment: @PaulF: You may be right but if so that was the worst clarification ever. ;-)

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer, format for numeric string depends on regional settings. I won't recommend methods in Edit#1 and Edit#2 section. This might be the reason of serious troubles,

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please read my comment to the question. As i mentioned there, string format for numeric values depends on regional settings. So, below line

```
mbar.HealthLabel.text = String.Format("{0:0.0}", _hp);
```

will return: **2,25** (as to the polish numeric standard)

In my opinion you need something like this:

```
mbar.HealthLabel.text = String.Format("{0:D}", Math.Floor(_hp*100));
```

For furhter details, please see:

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Up to Microsoft.NET Framework 4.7 there is no way to solve this when we are only allowed to modify the format string ("template"). All solutions require to either:

- Post-process the resulting string. Here, the closest for the special case with two decimals may be the % format
- Compute the numeric argument first to make it integer
- Write and apply a custom IFormatProvider implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *eliminate* the decimal separtor ("escape the dot", as you've put it), try *replacing* the decimal separator with *empty string*:

```
string result = String
 .Format("{0:0.0}", _hp)
 .Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, "");
```